# Parsing escaped separation character in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I just started using parsec and I am trying to do something simple.

I want to separate key-value strings, as shown in [this parsec tutorial](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html).

For example, the string `FirstN=Tom&LastN=Brady` should give `[["FirstN","Tom"],["LastN","Brady"]]`.

This is easy, but I would also like to allow the `'='` character in the string to be escaped. For example, the string `Equation=1+1\\=2` should give `[["Equation", "1+1\\=2"]]` (or `[["Equation","1+1=2"]]` but I haven't decided which is best yet).

For the simple example the parsing code is the following:

```
kvParser :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
kvParser input = parse kvString "Error text?" input

kvString = sepBy kvVal (char '&')
kvVal = sepBy (many (noneOf "=&")) (char '=')
```

To allow an escaped `=` I think I need to modify the `(char '=')` value but I'm not sure how. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

**Edit**: The final working parser is

```
kvParser :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
kvParser input = parse kvString "Error text?" input

kvString = sepBy kvVal (char '&')
kvVal = sepBy (many kvChar) (char '=')
kvChar = noneOf "\\&=" <|> (char '\\' >> anyChar)
```

I also got the following to work using a `try` combinator.

```
kvParser :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
kvParser input = parse kvString "Error text?" input

kvString = sepBy kvVal (char '&')
kvVal = sepBy (many kvChar) (char '=')
kvChar = try (string "\\=" >> return '=') <|> noneOf "&="
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The separator is fine; what you want is to accept `\=` as part of a key or value. Instead of

```
noneOf "=&"
```

you might try

```
(noneOf "\\&" <|> (char '\\' >> anyChar))
```

That is, `noneOf` will accept anything that isn't a backslash, otherwise the parser on the right will accept (and skip) a backslash and keep the character following it. That should prevent it being detected as a separator.

Comment: I replaced `noneOf "=&"` with `(noneOf "\\&" <|> (char '\\' >> anyChar))` but now it doesn't separate on `=` at all. It does eat the `\\\` values though.

Comment: OK, perhaps you need to add `=` back into the `noneOf` string. I admit I haven't actually tested it personally. I think `noneOf "\\=&"` will work...